# filename group by a pattern and select only one from each group

Tags: bash

I have following files(as an example, 60000+ actually) and all the log files follows this pattern:

```
    analyse-ABC008795-84865-201911261249.log
    analyse-ABC008795-84866-201911261249.log
    analyse-ABC008795-84867-201911261249.log
    analyse-ABC008795-84868-201911261249.log
    analyse-ABC008795-84869-201911261249.log
    analyse-ABC008796-84870-201911261249.log
    analyse-ABC008796-84871-201911261249.log
    analyse-ABC008796-84872-201911261249.log
    analyse-ABC008796-84873-201911261249.log
```

Only numbers get change in log files. I want to take one file from each category where files should be categorized by ABC.... number. So, as you can see, there are only two categories here:

```
analyse-ABC008795
analyse-ABC008796
```

So, what I want to have is one file(let's say first file) from each category. Output should look like this:

```
analyse-ABC008795-84865-201911261249.log
analyse-ABC008796-84870-201911261249.log
```

This should be done in Bash/linux environment, so that after I get this, I should use grep to check if my "searching string" contain in those files

```
ls -l | <what should I do to group and get one file from each category> | grep "searching string"
```

Comment: look at the `cut`, `sort`, and `uniq` commands. Chain them together. You don't want `ls -l`, just `/bin/ls` will suffice for this project. Hopefully there aren't any spaces or other "white-space" chars in your real filenames. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash` and `awk`.

```sh
files=(*.log)
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" | awk -F- '!seen[$2]++'
```

Or use `find` instead of a  `bash` array for a more portable approach.

```
find . -type f -name '*.log' | awk -F- '!seen[$2]++'
```

If your `find` has the `-printf` flag and you don't want the leading `./` from the filename add it before the pipe `|`

```
-printf '%f\n'
```

The `!seen[$2]++` Remove second and subsequent instances of each input line, without having to sort them first. The `$2` means the second field which `-F` is using.

Comment: Or with process substitution `awk -F- '!seen[$2]++' < <(find . -type f -name '*.log')` since tagged bash.